# How can make sound only play once in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

When the user trigger a condition，I need to play a sound once.It is in major cycle of while,so it always play many times.Please solve the little problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Include at the start of your loop the code `playsound = True`. Then in your loop put the following:

```
if playsound:
    # Play the sound
    playsound = False
```

Put your current command for playing in place of `# Play the sound`, it probably looks something like `sound.play()`.

Comment: I failed.Python did not play.

Comment: Have you put the command for playing the sound inside the if statement. If you're code currently says `MySound.play()`, this need to be in place of `# Play the sound` It would help if you posted your full code.

Comment: I am not so silly>_>.I find the reason.I play other music up and when pygame was playing this sound,up sound was playing,too.Pygame cannot play two sounds.So the second sound play lose.Thank you at last.Ask the childish question.Damn up sound!

Comment: Sometimes,sounds always have a quiet end.It's hard to tell when it ends.I have already tried using stop() to slove.Hh